# How to do bivariate or multicriteria line symbolization in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, legend

I'm trying to use QGIS to trace out an itinerary with a legend using color for the type of route and line thickness for the amount of traffic on the route.  I have seen that it's possible to do things like this in ArcGIS with a bivariate legend.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

from the "layer properties" and "Style" tab, chose "Graduate" Or "Categorized" then chose the "Column" with the "Size" you want to map, and under "Method" use "Size". Then classify your data and it will be nicely represented.

[image]